# Make Excel cell save formula results and not the actual formula?

Tags: microsoft-excel, cells, combine

I have C1 that needs to combine C2 and C3. The problem with this is that is that if I'm importing with SQL it doesn't combine C2 and C3, but instead imports nothing or the actual formula. Is there a way to make formula information in a cell more permanent?

For example; a field that I am using a formula for (`=A4`) is being imported (when in csv) as Excel Metadata rather than the contents of `A4`. How do I make the contents more "permanent" with excel?

Comment: Is there something wrong with using "=CONCATENATE(C2,C3)" in C1 and then just doing a copy-pastevalue (assuming I understood you right)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This topic helps to solve the issue](http://www.cybertechhelp.com/forums/showthread.php?t=19041):

> - Select all the cells
> - Edit - Copy - Paste Special - Select "values" - Click OK

Answer (score 1):

If you have a direct connection to a SQL server as your datasource, consider using a SQL statement in your connection instead of simply the table name.

It's not too complicated even if you're not familiar with SQL, and you should not run into access rights problems since you need SELECT rights to read the table in the first place.

Something like:

```
SELECT columnName1 + columnName2 as combinedColumn, * FROM Tablename
```

Screenshot:

[image]

This technique also works great when you wish to make a new column available to a PivotTable without resorting to an intermediary excel table.